# Simulate Drag and drop from terminal in X11

Tags: python, linux, drag-and-drop, x11

### INTRO

I am working on a terminal based file manager called [TUIFI](https://github.com/GiorgosXou/TUIFIManager#tuifi-manager), looking for ways to simulate drag-and-drop behaviours in X11 through terminals; **specifically for a basic XDND protocol implementation.**

### ISSUE

During my search for proper documentation, I encountered a limited amount of information regarding the XDND protocol. **As a result, I have been struggling to implement it in Python.**

### CONTEXT

I understand that I need to utilize the `Xlib` library and follow the steps outlined in [this](https://johnlindal.wixsite.com/xdnd/example-walk-through) guide to implement XDND. However, my [attempts](https://github.com/GiorgosXou/TUIFIManager/issues/21) at understanding and implementing it in Python have been unsuccessful so far. I have encountered difficulties and obstacles along the way.

### OUTRO

I have explored how other GUI libraries such as PySide and Tkinter handle similar functionality on GitHub, and I have also searched for basic XDND implementations. Unfortunately, I have not had any luck thus far. If you have any ideas or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate your input. **Thanks In advance**

Comment: https://github.com/GiorgosXou/TUIFIManager/discussions/92